# iphone applicationWillResignActive - get reason

Tags: iphone, audio, record, interruption

I wonder, if there's a way to get reason of applicationWillResignActive being called?

I'm developing an audio app, and I want to continue recording sound when the screen is auto locked, but I want to stop recording when incoming call occurs. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [AVAudioSessionDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSessionDelegate_ProtocolReference/Reference/Reference.html) protocol methods like: `beginInterruption` and/or `endInterruptionWithFlags:` to check if the recording is interrupted and than you can do whatever you need.

In this case this approach has an advantage over registering to telephony events, because it works all the time recording, and not only for the first 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the [Core Telephony Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009603) in your application. This framework gives you the possibility of listening to the events and state of the phone on your device.

Moreover, the [`CTCallCenter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) class gives you the possibility of registering to telephony events to appropriately handle them through your application. This way you will be able to call a specific callback when an incoming call arrives, a call is started, terminated and so on. See the [full list of cellular call states](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCall/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Cellular_Call_States).

Hope this helps.